# sql query return the sum of two records

Tags: mysql, math

In mysql,can be made a query to fetch the sum of two table records? :

```
    Table1

     Col1  Col2

Row1 1     2

Ro2  3     4
```

Col2: Row1+Row2=6

Something like SELECT Col2 FROM TABLE1 SUM(Row1+Row2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct you want:

```
select sum(Col2) from Table1
```